# how to disable ANR dialog on android achartengine layout zoom with 15000 points

Tags: android, achartengine, android-anr-dialog

In my program, i put achartengine lineplot in a layout.

I got an ANR dialog when i want to zoom in from 15000 points display. I know it will work, i have to wait and choose wait if ANR pop out. But im getting sick of clicking wait button everytime i wanna zoom. Anyone know how to disable this ANR dialog?

Comment: You get the ANR because you lock up the main thread too long. My guess is that you need to do the zooming work in another thread. Maybe the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html#WorkerThreads) could be your friend? Since you can update the UI from such a thread but still not lock the main thread.

Comment: Regarding disabling the dialog I don't think you can since it's there for a reason, and that is that you lock up the system.

Comment: Thanks guys. I used Asynctack to deal with it. cheers

Comment: With achart engine, the zoom pinch is not so responsive when you have a lot of points displayed , i improve my plotting by reducing the number of number plotted (fixed to 500 points per display) by taking only the maximum of certain number of points. I add a zoom listener so everytime the user zoom in, i replot it with more points in the zoomed area.

Comment: There's an open issue here: https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/issues/detail?id=267&can=1&q=zoom&sort=-id

Answer (score 2):

With achart engine, the zoom pinch is not so responsive when you have a lot of points displayed , i improve my plotting by reducing the number of number plotted (fixed to 500 points per display) by taking only the maximum of certain number of points. I add a zoom listener so everytime the user zoom in, i replot it with more points in the zoomed area.